# MMC SPI Issue not able to setup MMC/SD Card in Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, spi, mmc

I am currently writing a SPI Driver for a custom SPI IP which is used to interface MMC/SD Card. The SPI Driver is getting probed and the MMC driver is also getting probed. The MMC driver at the end prints this statement.

```
[   61.219787] mmc_spi spi0.0: SD/MMC host mmc0, no DMA, no WP, no poweroff, cd polling
```

I tried to print the value sent to the buffer while there are 29 bytes of 0xFF. These 29 bytes of 0xFF are being sent after which 18 and 10 are being sent from it and for which there is 0x00 from the read in that transfer_one function.

Will the number of write and read in the `transfer_one()` function be same?

And what does the MMC SPI driver try to do in this sequence?

Comment: Read this: http://www.rjhcoding.com/avrc-tutorials-home.php TL;DR: MMC SPI **abuses** SPI (signal) protocol. That's why non-standard sequences are required.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have got some understanding of SPI SD Card working. But I would like to know that if there are ways to check what the mmc-spi driver send is being sent out or being given back to it. I can only see 0xFF in a loop. Also, I am getting this as the message in dmesg : 
[26685.540374] mmc_spi spi0.0: setup mode 0, cs_high, 8 bits/w, 400000 Hz max --> 0
[26685.604003] mmc_spi spi0.0: setup mode 0, 8 bits/w, 400000 Hz max --> 0

I want to know why the sd card is not being detected?

Comment: Not every card supports SPI, only older ones. Also there is a dirty play with CS (chip select), be sure that it goes exactly to the state as MMC SPI driver wants it to be). Ah, yes, try the latest kernel for that (one is v5.13-rc3 and one from Linux Next) as well.

Comment: Thanks for the support. The issue was a logical issue where the total bits to be transmitted was not refreshed after each transfer. Also I am currently having this issue where the

[  152.547088] mmc_spi spi0.0: no support for card's volts
[  152.725311] mmc0: error -22 whilst initialising SDIO card
[  156.647918] mmc_spi spi0.0: no support for card's volts
[  156.824890] mmc0: error -22 whilst initialising SD card
[  159.290557] mmc_spi spi0.0: no support for card's volts
[  159.468292] mmc0: error -22 whilst initialising MMC card

This keeps looping till Card is inserted.

Comment: Try to disable DMA.